# Groups owner vs. member

Tags: usability, interaction-design

Ok,
Seems like a simple question, but I haven't found a great solution yet. The service has **groups**.

> Users can join a group and they can create a group.

So there is a page/screen where you can see the groups you've joined. There is also a page screen where you manage the groups you've created. Naturally, these needs to be different, look different and are reached through different channels.

I'm looking for insights or examples of how to differentiate these two features. I'm getting stuck with the problem of having

> - Groups I've joined
> - Group Management

As menu items or buttons since they seem so confusing and unclear. In addition like below is also clumsy and confusing.

> - Groups I'm a Member Of
> - Groups I Own

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there anyway!

I'd suggest perhaps, option one:

- **Groups I'm in**
- **Groups I manage**

making the distinction clear but emphasising that they're both "a set of groups" or, option two:

- **Group membership**
- **Group management**

but that risks the first looking like it's about "managing" the membership list, and the second then seems .. silly; and option three, based on various UX I've seen in the past:

- **My Groups**
- **Manage Groups**

although that doesn't really communicate *anything* about what the first does.

Comment: Yes, these are very good suggestions.   Perhaps #1 is the clearest. Though "Manage Groups" could still be confused with managing groups I'm in. and "My Groups" might mean groups I'm in or groups I own. And this is the crux of the issue.

Comment: Quite :)  If it's any help at all ... I'd suggest - gently - that your difficulty in differentiating them suggests that perhaps it would be better *not* to split them, or e.g. to have one view and a "filter" that restricts to those  you created? No one right answer, with this sort of thing.

Comment: Yes, I have considered that - a single list with either color or iconography (flair) to indication ownership/membership

Answer (score 2):

There was recently an interesting topic on using first person vs second person.

But apart from that, what about:

> *Groups:*
>
> - My creations / My ownership
> - My participation

or

> *Groups:*
>
> - You created / You own / You administer / You manage
> - You participate in

It still leaves some grey area as you can own a group AND participate in one, nevertheless the difference is clear and less clumsy.

Comment: I like this word "participation" - which really differentiates the two.  It makes me think of Teacher vs. Student and thus "class" - and so I can teach a class or register for a class... also clearly different.